# Не меняется значение модели в Angular 2?

Tags: angular2

Мне необходимо в поле при вводе букв или нецифровых символов выдать сообщение об ошибке и изменить значение переменной-модели. Этого не происходит. 
Фрагмент view:

```
<input type="string" pInputText [(ngModel)]="mdl_cargo_weight" 
   (ngModelChange)="checkCargoWeight()"/>
```

Фрагмент кода компонента

```
checkCargoWeight(){
if (!this.keyService.isNumber(this.mdl_cargo_weight)){ // ввели не цифру
    this.mdl_cargo_weight = "0";
    this.msg_error_display = true;
```

}

В обработчике события не изменяется модель, остается введенное значение - странная проблема. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А ангуляр в консоль предупреждение не пишет никакое?

Comment: Вот самое интересное - сам ang ничего не сообщает, словно так и надо. Причем другие модели в этом обработчике я могу легко менять, а редактируемую нет.

Comment: Сделай [mcve] на планкере. Кстати, возможно, значение меняется позже.

Comment: ты про FormsModule & ReactiveFormsModule не забыл?

Comment: @Artsiom, если б забыл, там бы вообще ошибка биндинга к несуществующей директиве была.

Comment: Не задействовал ReactiveFormsModule, каюсь. Но решил проблему довольно просто, хотя может это и не есть фэн-шуй Angulara - изменяю модель посредством setTimeOut в коллбэке, все работает. Все спасибо, кто помогал.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel